# Define ingress without the wildcard subdomain assigned to the Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an ingress controller answering that is answering to `*.mycompany.com`. Is it possible, whenever I define `Ingress` resources in my cluster, not to specify the whole thing `some-service.mycompany.com` but only the `some-service` part.

Thus, if I changed the domain name later on (or for example in my test env) I wouldn't need to specify `some-service.test.mycompany.com` but things would magically work without changing anything.

Comment: Could your provide our ingress YAML? Are you using bare metal or its somewhere in cloud?

Answer (score 0):

For most Ingress Controllers, if you don’t specify the hostname then that Ingress will be a default for anything not matching anything else. The only downside is you can only have one of these (per controller, depending on your layout).

Comment: I understand what you suggest but I am looking for something else. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration you want to achieve is possible only in `nginx` but it's impossible to apply it in `nginx-ingress` due to limitation of **"host:"**.

`"ingress-redirect" is invalid: spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "~^subdomain\\..+\\..+$;": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.',`.

It must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. `example.com`, regex used for validation is `[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')`
but nginx syntax allows to use syntax llike this: `< server_name mail.*; >`.

It would work if you put all configuration as `http_snippet`, but it's a lot of manual work (which you want to avoid).

I think the better solution is to use [HELM](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/). Put ingress yaml to `helm chart` and use `values.my_domain` in the chart to prepare Ingress object. Then all you need is to run 
`helm install ingress-chart-name --set values.my_domain=example.com`